# How to make the contents of a label to stay under the parent element when they fall to the next line?

Tags: html, css

In the following code, in both the `#option_one_div` and `#option_two_div`, when the contents of the `label` outgrow one line, the move to the next line, under the radio buttons. What I want is that they should stay under the text of their `label` in the previous line.

How can I do that?

I tried to enclose the `label`s in a `span` tag but that does not help. I can not enclose the `label`s in `div` elements because `div` is a `block` level element, so the entire `label` will fall to the next line. What should I do.

**[JSFiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/60kb0prm/2/)**

[image]

```
<div style="padding:25px; width:400px;">
        <div style="background-color:#bf5b5b; ">
            <label style="margin-left:25px; margin-right:25px;">Yes</label>
            <label style="margin-left:25px; margin-right:25px;">No</label>
            <label style="margin-left:25px; margin-right:25px;"></label>
        </div>
        <div id="option_one_div" style="background-color:#74d4dd;">
            <input style="margin-left:30px; margin-right:30px;" type="radio" name="radio" value="0">
            <input style="margin-left:30px; margin-right:30px;" type="radio" name="radio" value="1">
            <label style="margin-left:25px; margin-right:25px;" for="option_one_div">Label of first group of Radio Buttons radio buttons.</label>
        </div>
        <div id="option_two_div" style="background-color:#36d666;">
            <input style="margin-left:30px; margin-right:30px;" type="radio" name="radio" value="0">
            <input style="margin-left:30px; margin-right:30px;" type="radio" name="radio" value="1">
            <label style="margin-left:25px; margin-right:25px;" for="option_two_div">Label of second group of Radio Buttons radio buttons.</label>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This isn't the recommended way to construct form elements. Ideally you should have a label "for" each radio button, rather than labelling a div. See http://www.websemantics.co.uk/tutorials/accessible_forms/

Comment: @ialarmedalien Yes it is unusual but it is my requirement.

Comment: For accessibility, you should give the `<input>` elements a `<label>`, even if you hide it using css.

Comment: @ialarmedalien How can I hide it through CSS?

Comment: There are various methods, depending on how your html is structured. See http://webaim.org/techniques/css/invisiblecontent/, http://css-tricks.com/places-its-tempting-to-use-display-none-but-dont/, and https://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/form-labels-visible-hidden-53548.html for some examples.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options:

- put the form in a table
- use `display: table-row` and `display: table-cell` to mimic a table
- set widths on your input and label elements and float them inside the div
- set widths on your input and label elements and use `display: inline-block`

Comment: I can not use a table.

Comment: Your example is a bit advanced for a newb =(

Comment: Which part(s) of the example are causing the problems? There are a few things that need to be changed in your original code to correct the html for the form; was that causing confusion?